# Internal & External validation of ordinal outcome

Tags: ordinal-data, validation, regression-strategies

For binary outcomes, I have used bootstrapping approach (Frank Harrell's R package `rms`) for internal validation and Cox framework for external validation. More information is [here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3575184/)

I know there is [multiCalibration](https://user2015.math.aau.dk/presentations/53.html#1) package in R, but this is for Multinomial outcome.

Would it be tricky to do internal and external validation for ordinal outcome such as cancer stages? Any direction in this regards would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The R `rms` package with the `lrm` and `orm` function and associated `calibrate` and `validate` functions also allows for strong internal validation of models for ordinal $Y$.

Comment: Thank you. It's helpful. Can I assume cancer stages as multinomial outcome to get calibration slope (external validation) using multiCalibration?

Comment: No it needs to be assumed to be ordinal.  By calibration I mean a validation of Prob(Y >= j) for various j.  For each Y >= j this is a binary validation but predictions come from the unified ordinal model.

Comment: If I would like to do test the developed model on new center data, can I validate this using calibrate or validate?
Would it be tricky to apply Cox framework (calibration in-the-large, calibration slopes)?

Comment: For external validation (which works if sample sizes are huge) use `val.prob`.

Comment: Thank you. If sample sizes are not huge such 300 in each center?

Comment: I go into more detail in fharrell.com/doc/bbr.pdf but the short answer is that if n < 20,000 split sample validate is too noisy, i.e., if you split again you'll get results are are too different from the first split.  Strong interval validation using the bootstrap is better for the non-huge N case.